# Как передать из функции значение, чтобы запустить другую функцию?

Tags: c

В данном коде я создаю в функции get_str массив символов. Затем я хочу результат работы этой функции передать в функцию slenght, которая должна выводить размер этой строки(массива символов). И затем я хочу организовать вывод значения функции slenght в main. Подскажите, как это сделать? Я не понимаю как передать str из первой функции во вторую. Или как вызвать функцию get_str из функции slenght.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
char get_str(){
    size_t length = 0; 
    char* str = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    if (str == NULL) { 
        return 1;}   
    printf("Write string and press ENTER to continue:\n");
    while (1){ 
        char c = getchar();
        if (c == 10) break; 
        length++; 
        str[length - 1] = c;}
    return str;
}
//int slenght(get_str){
//    int len = -1;
//    while (++len, *str++);
//    return len;}


int main() {
    slenght(get_str);
    return 0;}
```

Comment: `char * get_str() { ... return str;}` и `int slength (char *str) { ... }` и тогда, например, получится  `main() { ... printf("%d\n", slength(get_str())); ..}` (а сейчас вы пытаетесь передать функцию, а не *результат ее работы*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_str` == адрес функции ; `get_str()` == результат вызова функции. Возвращать надо не одну букву, а их массив. `char * get_str(){..`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int slenght(char const * );

char * get_str(){
    size_t length = 0; 
    char* str = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    if (str == NULL) { 
        return NULL;
    }   
    printf("Write string and press ENTER to continue:\n");
    while (1){ 
        char c = getchar();
        if (c == 10)
          break; 
        length++; 
        str[length - 1] = c;
    }
    return str;
}

int slenght(char const * str){
    int len = -1;
    while (++len, *str++)
      ;
    return len;
}

int main() {
  int len = slenght(get_str());
  return 0;
}
```

и чтобы не терять выделенную память надо указатель сохранить в переменную

```c
  char * str ;
  int len = slenght(str = get_str());
  free ( str ) ;
```

Comment: `10` надо бы заменить на `\n`. `while(1)` содержит ошибку переполнения буфера. Эти рекомендации можно добавить в ответ, чтобы автор не мучился потом с говнокодом.